# Programmarically selecting a particular HdyPreferencesPage in libhandy

Tags: c, gtk, gnome

In GNOME libhandy, I got a HdyPreferencesWindow which contains some HdyPreferencesPage instances (that display as tabs).

How do I programmatically select/show a particular tab? There seems to be no public API to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was told in https://matrix.to/#/#libhandy:talk.puri.sm that there is no way to do this in libhandy and was suggested to migrate to GTK4 and libadwaita.

You can, however, fish for the GTK pages stack and talk to it directly, but that bypasses the public API.